# How to allow WordPress users create sub-website or mini-website under my domain with any basic site builder?

Tags: multisite

I want to allow my WordPress website users to create their own mini-pages within my site with the possibility of allowing them to select from a list of one-page themes i can provide.

Example of what I'm looking for: https://www.weddingwire.ca/wedding-websites

Mainly i need to:
-let a user create a page
-let users select from pre-defined themes
-let users be able to make basic edits to their own page
-let the user upload photos and edit text on the page

the result could be director or subdomain, i don't care as long as the result is:
[www.mydomain.com/user-mini-website](http://www.mydomain.com/user-mini-website)
OR
user-mini-website.mydomain.com

I will appreciate help with ready plugins or minimal development and as much explanation as possible, as i don't have coding experience.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

I have done something similar. You can do this with WordPress out of the box - no development required.

How I did this was to use WordPress in multisite mode. You can select the themes that are network-enabled (available to all users).

[Here is the official guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/) to using WordPress in multisite mode. You can run this as subdomain or sub-folder

Enable user registration and site creation and you have just completed your project.

I would suggest you explore BuddyPress which I use to allow all my users' posts to appear on the main site. However, that is a new level of complexity that might not be right for you.

You can force plugins to always be active (network activate) or allow users to optionally activate them. To hide some plugins, I believe I used another plugin but it has been too long and I do not remember.